# Ubuntu 14.04 Netbeans 8.0 can't create a new project

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

Somebody help me, I'm spending much time trying to create any netbeans project such as java library, when i change the target path to outside from workspace i can create, if the target is workspace show the message project folder cannot be created. I tried to change the permissions workspace with chmod 777 but not work, operation system Ubuntu 14.04 and netbeans 8.0 follow the image, thank you!

[netbeans error]http://i62.tinypic.com/20thr7l.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no /home/workspace directory in your machine.

Most probably, you must create the project under /home/youruser/workspace, where youruser is the result of the whoami command.

Comment: Man, thak you for reply, you almost correct i change the target to home/myuser/workspace and work, but there is home/workspace in my machine, because "my existing resources" are there, i wanted to create this project in this workspace because this directory already linked with my github any idea what happen?

Comment: check /home/workspace directory permissions. Probably you're not being allowed to create a new directory up there.